Dictionary.ContainsKey() doesn't work as expected
I'm currently trying to solve the first Leetcode problem (Two Sum):

Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices
of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and
you may not use the same element twice.
You can return the answer in any order.
Example 1:
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Explanation: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
Example 2:
Input: nums = [3,2,4], target = 6
Output: [1,2]
Example 3:
Input: nums = [3,3], target = 6
Output: [0,1]

Here's my code:
public class Solution {
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        Dictionary<int, int> hash = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        int n = nums.Count();

        for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
            int complement = target - nums[i];
            if (hash.ContainsKey(complement)) {
                int[] solution = new int[]{(int)i, (int)hash[complement]};
                return solution;
            }
            else {
                hash.Add(nums[i], i);
            }
        }

        return new int[]{};
    }

This code works fine until I get a list containing the same element several times.
For example:
Inputs : nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Returns : [1,0]
Inputs : nums = [1,1,1,1,1,4,1,1,1,1,1,7,1,1,1,1,1] target = 11
Returns : "Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1"
So the program is trying to add another '1' key in my dictionary. I think it's because even if the value is the same, the object is different, but i can't find how to solve this.
Any help ? Thanks!
I just want to point out that this algorithm works perfectly. See this code in Python (works):
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        hash = {}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            complement = target - nums[i]
            if complement in hash:
                return [i, hash[complement]]
            else:
                hash[nums[i]] = i

        return []


Check the dictionary first to see if it already contains the value that you are trying to insert. A hash set does not allow duplicate entries.

You check for the existence of complement in the dictionary but then add nums[i] when missing. complement and nums[i] aren't the same thing.

You can't use a dictionary to solve this issue.  The example input [3,3] would require putting the number 3 twice in the dictionary key and you can only have one number in a dictionary with the same key.  May be you should use the index for the key instead of the number.

Please note, that Add throws exception when you try to add the same key; you can use TryAdd instead
public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
     ...
     else {
         // Add a new key if and only if it doesn't exist
         hash.TryAdd(nums[i], i);
     }
     ...
}

Your code simplified (.Length instead of Count(), TryGetValue instead of Contains etc.):
public class Solution {
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        var hash = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; ++i) 
            if (hash.TryGetValue(target - nums[i], out int index)) 
                return new int[]{index, i};
            else 
                hash.TryAdd(nums[i], i);

        return Array.Empty<int>();
    }
}

Please, fiddle yourself
Edit: Note, that you check different keys, e.g. for nums = {1, 1, ...} and target = 11 you have for the second item

hash contains single 1 key
complement = 11 - 1 = 10
you check hash.ContainsKey(complement) get false (hash doesn't contain 10)
you try to add 1 (note, 1 not 10) and get the exception


Thanks, your suggestion works. I just don't understand why the program enters the 'else', when it's only supposed to enter it when the key isn't already present in 'hash' (the if).

@Simon Naulet: you work with different keys: you check for complement (say, 10 which is not in hash) and then try to add current item (say, 1 which is in hash)
